# Will there be potential difference across a resistor if the circuit is open?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

In such an open circuit, will there be  potential difference across the resistor? More specifically, will charges accumulate on the left side of the resistor? or will it be able to flow through the resistor and stop at the open end, resulting in 0 potential difference. Because if charges were to accumulate on the left of the resistor, that would mean there can be a potential difference across the resistor even though there is no current?

Comment: No current, no potential difference.

Answer (score 3):

Both sides of the resistor will be at the same potential, so there will be no potential difference. We use the term potential difference because potentials are only defined up to the addition of an arbitrary constant. Thus, if we say the potential on each side of the resistor was zero before the cell was connected then the potential on both sides of the resistor will still be zero after the cell is connected and if the positive side of the cell was connected as in your diagram then the potential of the negative side of the cell would be -5V (assuming the 5V cell). Alternatively, if only the negative side of the cell was connected then the resistor would still have zero potential on either side after the cell is connected and the positive side of the cell would be at 5V.